# What is spt_columns_odbc_view and why is it not accessible?

Tags: sql-server

I did `sp_helptext 'sys.sp_columns'` and saw that the the underlying table is `sys.spt_columns_odbc_view`, but I could not execute queries as I get `Invalid object name 'sys.spt_columns_odbc_view'`.

Is this system table not queryable or am I lacking rights? Not much documentation is provided in msdn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a DAC connection first, 
because sys.spt_columns_odbc_view is internal view.
After you make DAC, simply query it, like that:

```
select * from sys.spt_columns_odbc_view
```

[More info on DAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)